# Git: Get username vs number of lines for a particular file type in HEAD

Tags: git, blame

I wanted to measure the number of lines of code for each developer in the tip of develop branch at this point of time for python files. How can I make that happen?

More like this: Initialise a counter for each developer to 0. For each python file in project, blame each line. Increment the counter of the respective developer.

I do not want the overall addition deletion numbers. Only what exists in the HEAD of the branch.

Comment: Are you looking for something like this : `git blame <filename>`. Ex: `git blame <filename> | grep <Username> | wc -l`

Answer (score 0):

Try this bash one-liner:

```
find -name '*.py' -type f -exec git annotate  -e -- {} \; | cut -f2 -d $'\t' | grep -oP '[^<>]{2,}' | sort | uniq -c
```

It outputs not names, but e-mails.

Comment: Hmm, it works for me. 
I have: find (GNU findutils) 4.4.2, bash 4.2.25, git 2.6.2.
Try to delete '--', it should work too